# why getting Invalid keyword: PROPERTY error in orientdb?

Tags: java, orientdb, tinkerpop

I am new to orientdb and trying to run the below command from the java code library, but getting Invalid keyword: PROPERTY error. Where as the same command works perfect in orientdb studio. Not able to understand why it is not working though code.

```
CREATE CLASS User
CREATE PROPERTY User.firstName String
CREATE PROPERTY User.password String
ALTER PROPERTY User.password NOTNULL = true
```

I am using tinkerpop java library for development. and below is the code which executes the command.

```
 OrientGraph graph = graphFactory.getTx();
 int modified = graph.command(
                          new OCommandSQL(command)).execute();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi GuruKulki, could you post the entire executed code and the stack trace that you get ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to reproduce your issue you can't put all those instruction inside the variable command, you have to run them separately, I give you two way to do it:

**1st Attempt**

```
        OrientGraphFactory graphFactory=new OrientGraphFactory(path+DB);
        OrientGraph graph=graphFactory.getTx();

        List<String> Command=new ArrayList<String>();
        Command.add("CREATE CLASS User");
        Command.add("CREATE PROPERTY User.firstName String");
        Command.add("CREATE PROPERTY User.password String");
        Command.add("ALTER PROPERTY User.password NOTNULL true");

        for(int i=0;i<Command.size();i++)
        {
            String command=Command.get(i);
            graph.command(new OCommandSQL(command)).execute();
        }
```

**2nd Attempt**

```
        String command="CREATE CLASS User";
        int modified=graph.command(new OCommandSQL(command)).execute();

        String command2="CREATE PROPERTY User.firstName String";
        int modified2=graph.command(new OCommandSQL(command2)).execute();

        String command3="CREATE PROPERTY User.password String";
        int modified3=graph.command(new OCommandSQL(command3)).execute();

        String command4="ALTER PROPERTY User.password NOTNULL true";
        graph.command(new OCommandSQL(command4)).execute();
```

Hope it helps